# Sending MQTT messages to AWS IoT Mqtt broker using Seeduino

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, aws-iot, arduino-yun

I've been trying to connect the Seeduino microcontroller to the AWS IoT platform to send MQTT messages. I've started with basic PubSub example provided by Amazon SDK kit provided here: https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-arduino-yun/tree/master/AWS-IoT-Arduino-Yun-Library/examples/BasicPubSub

Here is the header code after I modified it to connect to AWS:

```
// Copy and paste your configuration into this file
//===============================================================
#define AWS_IOT_MQTT_HOST "a39furswz813o0.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"   // your endpoint
#define AWS_IOT_MQTT_PORT 8883                  // your port
#define AWS_IOT_CLIENT_ID "iotconsole-1520362244976-0"           // your client ID
#define AWS_IOT_MY_THING_NAME "Seed1"           // your thing name
#define AWS_IOT_ROOT_CA_FILENAME "root-CA.crt"           // your root-CA filename
#define AWS_IOT_CERTIFICATE_FILENAME "d48740b57e-certificate.pem.crt"                 // your certificate filename
#define AWS_IOT_PRIVATE_KEY_FILENAME "d48740b57e-private.pem.key"              // your private key filename
```

Is there anything I have wrong in the header code that I have wrong that could cause this problem? I haven't modified the BasicPubSub code. How else do I know that it's connected to AWS platform or not? Thanks in advance?

Comment: What problem?  Please update your post to include the issue you're having.

Comment: There's nothing published in the AWS MQTT IoT. I can't tell why this is happening

Comment: Please update your question with the policy you created and attached to your "thing".